# How can I make all question marks, for example, in the text, be a certain color?

Tags: html, css, colors

Is there a way to, for example, make every question mark, or exclamation point, or comma, etc. conform to a particular style, without having to wrap each one in a `div` or `span` for that style?

Comment: *"without having to wrap each one in a div or span for that style"*. Unfortunately, this is the only way.

Comment: you could use javascript and regular expressions to find each one and auto wrap it

Answer (score 2):

One way is to dynamically add `span` with a certain class to all question marks. You can do this with PHP `str_replace()` function for example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what I was talking about using regular expressions. You can add additional punctuation into the expression too:

```
string = $('p').text();
string = string.replace(/(['&.!,])/g,"<span>$1</span>");
$('p').html(string);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/g3gbru9j/1/)